# Wordpress: Form submit in admin does not set is_admin() true

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin to show a form in admin that inputs some data from user.

This form submits to this url:

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/my_settings_save.php

But when this url is called, although its an admin url, it does not set `is_admin()` to `true` and thus my admin handling code does not get called.

This is the handling code:

```
if ( is_admin() )
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/core.php';
else
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'public/core.php';
```

When the form is called first time, `is_admin()` is `true`... but when the posted url (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/my_settings_save.php) is called, `is_admin()` returns `false` and thus my `admin/core.php` is not called.

Any suggestions...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I found out to solve the issue:

First of all, the form should be posted to admin-post.php

2nd, there should be a hidden variable "action"

so the form should be like:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_settings_save">
    ....
</form>
```

Now the `is_admin()` is true and my admin core file is called successfully.

In that admin core file, I only set this action:

```
add_action('admin_post_my_settings_save', 'my_settings_save_function');
function my_settings_save_function()
{
    ...
}
```

and it works like a charm!